# Different approaches on boolean simplification gives different results.

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

The question is **A'B'C' + B'CD' + ABD + A'BCD + AB'C'D'**.
Also shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcCTM.png) which has the $2$ approaches I was going for.

When entering it on this [site](https://www.boolean-algebra.com/), it failed to simplify further, as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SEY0.png)

What is the reason that if you go for option $2$ you won't be able to get the final answer?
Or is there a way to get the final answer but the site can't figure it out?
Or are there some rules which prevent me from going to option $2$?
Or am I wrong entirely?

Comment: Looking for your visit,and check to my answer @work work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the website, is the problem, other websites simplify option 2 back to option 1
Try [this website](http://www.bool-simplifier.com/), paste this: `(A'*B'*C')+B*D*(A+C)+B'*D'*(A+C)`,so to your question:

> "is there a way to get the final answer but the site can't figure it out? "

***Yes, there is!***

## The steps to convert option 2 to 1:

$$
A'B'C'+BD(A+C)+B'D'(A+C)=A'B'C'+ABD+CBD+AB'D'+CB'D'$$$$
=(A'B'C'+AB'D'+CB'D')+ABD+CBD$$$$
=B'(A'C'+AD'+CD')+ABD+CBD$$$$
=B'(A'C'+(AD'+CD'))+ABD+CBD$$$$
=B'(A'C'+D'(A+C))+ABD+CBD$$$$
=B'(D'(A+C)+A'C')+ABD+CBD$$$$
=B'(D'(A'C')'+A'C')+ABD+CBD    ...[a+b=(a'b')']$$$$
=B'(D'+A'C')+ABD+CBD   ...[*]$$$$
=B'D'+A'B'C'+ABD+CBD $$$$
=B'D'+ABD+CBD+A'B'C'
$$

##### hence proved!

***[*** * ***] It's the redundancy law, identity b "$A+A'B=A+B$", where $A=A'C',B=D'$, in that step.

This is what the site should have not probably figured out, because the photo below says that the identity is not so popular!***
[image]